# automating silverlight applet with .net reflection

Tags: c#, silverlight, automation, code-injection

This is my first question on stackoverflow and it is related to automation of Silverlight applet. I would like to achieve a specific functionality and would appreciate if anybody can point me out the way.
My client has online forms in a form of silverlight applet. Silverlight applet is loaded in IE by navigating to intranet url. I need to locate some editable fields on that forms and fill them with values. In my first attempt to implement this requirement I used MS UI Automation API, but performance was very poor and I couldn’t easily achieve desired functionality. What I am trying to do now is to inject managed code in IE, for the simplicity sake let’s assume I could do it with BHO, and automate Silverlight applet using .net reflection. 
The Silverlight object is embedded via object html element.

```
 <object data="data:application/x-oleobject;..." width="100%" type="application/x-silverlight-2" height="100%">
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/CRM.xap">
</object>
```

I can to download and extract assemblies from CRM.xap. I can open with reflector those assemblies and see classes I need to work with.

My problem is that I don’t know how get to those classes, because I don’t even see them loaded in process.
Here is a code sample of what I am trying to achieve

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        delegate void DownloadCompleteDelegate();

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new DownloadCompleteDelegate(tryit));
        }

        object silverlight;

        void tryit()
        {
            SHDocVw.WebBrowser wb = webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance as SHDocVw.WebBrowser;
            IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = wb.Document as IHTMLDocument2;

            IHTMLDocument3 doc3 = doc2 as IHTMLDocument3;
            IHTMLElementCollection coll = doc3.getElementsByTagName("OBJECT");

            IHTMLObjectElement objElem = coll.item(0) as IHTMLObjectElement;
            object o = objElem.@object;


            silverlight = objElem.@object;
            XcpControlLib.IXcpControl control = silverlight as XcpControlLib.IXcpControl;       
            dynamic content = control.Content;
            XcpControlLib.IXcpObject obj = content as XcpControlLib.IXcpObject;
            dynamic grid = content.FindName("LayoutRoot");           

         //grid is of type ComObject.
         System.Windows.Controls.Grid theGrid = grid as System.Windows.Controls.Grid;
         //Fail to cast, theGrid is null    
        }
```

I would expect that theGrid variable would reference managed object, but casting fails. Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If doesn't have to be MS UI Automation API, I can suggest another option. I've used the MS one, in the past for WPF and Silverlight and replaced it successfully with [Telerik test framework](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework). It's free and very easy, once configured. The .Net reflection also was one of the things that I've used with it.